# SoapUI tests run in Maven don't hit Tomcat

Tags: maven, soapui

I was instructed to write up some SoapUI tests for our web service. The tests pass when run in soap ui, but fail when running mvn soapui:test. In fact no logging appears in the Tomcat console, leading me to suspect the test isn't even hitting the server.

The surefire reports don't list any errors, but the Maven output shows this

```
11:49:32,779 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Setting project property [message] to [*** SoapUI project test file located! ***]
[ERROR] java.lang.NullPointerException
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] brt-ws-api ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.919s]
[INFO] brt-ws-svc ......................................... FAILURE [  7.932s]
```

The no context NullPointerException. No stack trace even with -X.

Comment: can you provide your ```pom.xml```?

Comment: ... for `brt-ws-svc` module and if relative, of its parent

Comment: Here is the POM and the parent POM it references. Neither had the soapui plugin, so I also dug through and found the POM that contains it, it's the third you'll find in this pastebin.

http://pastebin.com/pX2ng0KB

Thanks!